# Inexistence of a dual to discrete metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The discrete metric has the interesting property that if a sequence $(a_n)$ converges with respect to that metric, then $(a_n)$ converges with respect to any other metric. I would like to prove that there is no metric that achieves the 'opposite', that is, a metric $d$ such that if a sequence diverges with respect to $d$, then the sequence diverges with respect to any other metric in $X$.

If useful, what I tried to do was to think about convergence in terms of the topology induced by the metric. Thus, the property of the discrete metric comes from the fact that the discrete topology is the finest topology. Intuitively, if a metric induced the trivial topology, then we would have the opposite property to that of the discrete metric, but this is not possible because such topology is not metrizable. However, that alone does not solve my problem, as we could still have a *metrizable* topology that is less refined than any other *metrizable* topology. I believe that this is not true. Thus, I was trying to think of an example where I have two metrizable topologies that are not comparable to each other and are not more refined than a third.

I appreciate if someone can help me following this line of reasoning, but I also accept other approaches.

Comment: If $X$ is a finite set, then every metric on $X$ has this property. Because every metric generates discrete topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a metric exists, if and only if $X$ is finite.

We need the following lemma:

Let $X$ be a set, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a pairwise distinct sequence in $X$, $x \in X$.
Then there exists a metric $e$ on $X$, such that
$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $x$.

PROOF. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $x_n \neq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
Then define
$e(x_n, x_m) = |\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}|, 
 e(x_n, x) = e(x, x_n) = \frac{1}{n},
 e(y,y) = 0$
and $e(y, z) = 1$, else.

Now, as pointed out by freakish, "$\Leftarrow$" is trivial. 
"$\Rightarrow$":
Let $d$ be such a metric on $X$.
Assume $X$ is infinite and choose a pairwise distinct sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. Since in a T2 space, a sequence converges to at most one point, there is an $x \in X$, such that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ does not converge to $x$ with respect to $d$.
By the lemma, there is metric $e$ on $X$ such that
$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \rightarrow x$ with respect to $e$.
Hence also the sequence $(x_1, x, x_2, x, x_3, x, \dots)$ converges to $x$ with respect to $e$. However, this sequence does not converge (to any point) with respect to $d$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks